# Validating objects with xeipuuv/gojsonschema

Tags: json, go, jsonschema

And I'm using `xeipuuv/gojsonschema` to receive a json file, this json file will be a future validator for other jsons that will be received, so it would be

1 - Receive a JSON, which is a jsonschema to validate a JSON

2 - When receiving a JSON input, validate with the jsonschema received in step 1 :

`{ "object1": { "properties", }, "object2": { "properties", } }`

However, I could not validate it because I always received the error that "object1" is necessary, and there is "object1"
And inside each object, there would be other validations like if there is a title, if there is an id, a birthdate

However, I could not validate it because I always received the error that "object1" is necessary, and there is "object1"

And inside each object, there would be other validations like if there is a title, if there is an id, a birthdate

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] that reproduces this behavior. Otherwise we're just guessing what you're doing.